# Error while removing package lazarus-src-2.2: dpkg-divert: error: file name 'to' is not an absolute path

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I'm trying to remove the "lazarus-src-2.2" package on my Ubuntu system, but I'm encountering an error that I can't resolve. Here's the output of the **`sudo apt remove lazarus-src-2.2`** command:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  lazarus-src-2.2
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 158 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... currently installed 586632 files and directories.)
Removing lazarus-src-2.2 (2.2.0+dfsg1-5ubuntu1) ...
dpkg-divert: error: file name 'to' is not an absolute path

Use --help for help about diverting files.
dpkg: error processing package lazarus-src-2.2 (--remove):
 installed lazarus-src-2.2 package post-removal script returned error exit status 2
Too many errors encountered, stopping
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lazarus-src-2.2
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I solve this issue and successfully remove the "lazarus-src-2.2" package? I've tried reinstalling the package and using the dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq command, but with no success. Any help would be appreciated!

**`sudo apt list | grep "lazarus"`**

```
lazarus-2.2/jammy,jammy 2.2.0+dfsg1-5ubuntu1 all
lazarus-doc-2.2/jammy,jammy,now 2.2.0+dfsg1-5ubuntu1 all [installed]
lazarus-doc/jammy,jammy,jammy 2.2.0+dfsg1-5ubuntu1 all
lazarus-ide-2.2/jammy,jammy,now 2.2.0+dfsg1-5ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
lazarus-ide-gtk2-2.2/jammy,now 2.2.0+dfsg1-5ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
lazarus-ide-gtk2/jammy,jammy 2.2.0+dfsg1-5ubuntu1 all
lazarus-ide-qt5-2.2/jammy 2.2.0+dfsg1-5ubuntu1 amd64
lazarus-ide-qt5/jammy,jammy 2.2.0+dfsg1-5ubuntu1 all
lazarus-ide/jammy,jammy,now 2.2.0+dfsg1-5ubuntu1 all [installed]
lazarus-src-2.2/jammy,jammy,now 2.2.0+dfsg1-5ubuntu1 all [installed]
lazarus-src/jammy,jammy,jammy 2.2.0+dfsg1-5ubuntu1 all
lazarus/jammy,jammy 2.2.0+dfsg1-5ubuntu1 all
```

**`uname -a`**

`Linux user-pc 5.15.0-73-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: It might be helpful to [edit] your question to include the output of `dpkg-divert --list` or at least `dpkg-divert --list 'lazarus*'`

Comment: @steeldriver thanks! I added a reply, with your command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And so, I solved this problem after a few days.
You need to delete the conflicting files with the

**`sudo dpkg-divert --remove PATH`**

Everything you might need to fix this error I put into 1 bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get a list of diversions with paths
diversions=$(dpkg-divert --list 'lazarus*')

# Split the output into strings
IFS=$'\n'

# Passing through each line of output
For line in $diversions; do
  # Extract the path from the line
  path=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')

  # Execute the command with the path substituted
  sudo dpkg-divert --remove --no-rename "$path"

#Remove the rest of the garbage
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt autoremove

done
```

P.S. you can replace the package name **'lazarus'** (line: 4) with any of your packages